# How do I produce a .SRM file containing string resources?

Tags: delphi

The example I am looking at is in the TurboPower [FlashFiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpflashfiler/) database.

It has, for example, a file ffclcnst.rc which contains

```
FF_CLIENT_STRINGS RCDATA FFCLCNST.SRM
```

and I can run

```
BRCC32 ffclcnst.rc
```

at the command prompt which seems to compile the .SRM file into a .RES file, but I cannot see how to change the information in the .SRM file. It appears to come from the ffclcnst.str file so I assume there is some way to convert the .STR file into the .SRM file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The readme](http://tpflashfiler.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tpflashfiler/flashfiler/readme.txt?view=log) tells you:

> Most of FlashFiler's error messages are stored in string resource
>   files having the extension STR. If you change these files, you must
>   recompile them using the TurboPower String Resource Manager located at
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsrmgr

Please note that these are not standard Windows string resources. They're something TurboPower made up. For a full explanation, be sure to read the [String Resource Manager's documentation](http://tpsrmgr.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tpsrmgr/srmgr/doc/readme.html?view=log). You can make an ordinary [string-table resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381050.aspx) in your .rc file, or you can skip the .rc file altogether and declare [`resourcestring` constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Resource_Strings) directly in your Delphi code. Unless you're editing TurboPower code, or you need to support ancient Delphi versions, I recommend you just use normal string tables.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I am debugging the FlashFiler code so I will probably initially try to fit with their approach.